# How to pass variable to Redirect tag

Tags: templating, redirect

I have a fruit Link it field that I use to allow users to choose an entry and have that page redirect to the chosen entry.  Not sure of the syntax to use to pass that link it field to the redirect field.

This does not work:

```
{% redirect "{{ block.redirect.url }}"  %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
{% redirect block.redirect.url %}
```

I don't know Linkit but this would be the correct twig syntax at least. For normal entry fields you would do

```
{% redirect block.redirect.one.url %}
```